# Preserving "MessageSigned" attachments while convert email from .msg formato into .eml

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a code that converts email from .msg into .eml format. I have tried many libraries, but I always face the same issue: the attachments of type "MessageSigned" (which are signed outlook file) are not  preserved while converting the email. I can't even save this type of attachments in a specified folder.
With a modified version of the `outlookmsgfile.py` library I face the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lmilli\SnidifcaPython2\SaveAttachments.py", line 52, in <module>
    save_attachments(msg_file_path, save_folder)
  File "C:\Users\lmilli\SnidifcaPython2\SaveAttachments.py", line 28, in save_attachments
    attachment_file.write(attachment.data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'MessageSigned'
```

I have tried to attach the file directly to the eml file, and I have also tried to save the signed attachment before adding it to the eml file.

Does anyone know a way to convert the email while preserving all types of attachments (including signed attachments)?